# Convert DB2 SQL query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, db2

I have to convert a DB2 query to SQL Server, but don't understand what exactly below query does:

```
SELECT 
    t.MyColumnA NAME(MyColumnA-01),
    t.MyColumnA COLHDG("COA" "VALUE")
FROM 
    MyTable t
```

Comment: Where does that query come from? Is it DB2 SQL that you're trying to convert to T-SQL, or is it T-SQL that you're trying to understand what it does?

Comment: `COLHDG` (and presumably `NAME`) is a DDS, or Data Definition Script (?) attribute on the iSeries, and I don't _think_ is valid in SQL (although that particular flavor has some extra oddities).  It was used because field names were limited to about 8 characters, so the other attributes were useful for some display utilities.  Is that actually what you have, or what?

Comment: It's not valid DB2 for i syntax....by chance are you dealing with the 3rd party Sequel product from help systems?  https://www.helpsystems.com/product-lines/sequel  That has some additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `NAME` and `COLHDG` functions are just UI functions specific to HelpSystems.  The actual query would be

```
SELECT t.MyColumnA AS "COA VALUE"
FROM MyTable t
```